# Why do 'Convert.ToInt32' and 'as int?' work differently?

Tags: c#, sql

```
Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar()); // Returns 100, because myCommand is a SQL command that gets a non-null BigInt cell
myCommand.ExecuteScalar() as int? ?? 0; //Returns 0 even when myCommand is SQL command that gets a non-null BigInt cell
```

I have to use the second way in this case, because myCommand.ExecuteScalar() can return `DBNull`. But why does the second way return a different result than `Convert.ToInt32`?

EDIT: Thank you, all. Changed type to Int64 and it's working now.

Comment: `as` will never perform a representation-changing conversion: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Converting and casting (with the cast operator, `is` operator and `as` operator) are two different things:

- Convert is changing one type to another type. Like from a `string` or `Int64` to an `Int32`.
- Casting can only be done from a base type to inheriting type. In this case from `object` to `Int32`. The `object` MUST contain an `Int32` to succeed. In your case it does not and the cast will return `null`.

In code:

```
Int64 l = 100;
object o = l;
Int32 i1 = o as Int32? ?? 0; // Cast fails, so "as" will return 0. "??" will make it 0.
Int32 i2 = Convert.ToInt32(o); // The Int32 inside the object will be converted into an Int32 and will return 100.
```

Comment: Casts don't return null, they throw exceptions. The `as` operator catches that exception and THEN returns `default(typeRequested)` which is `null` for reference types and can depend for value types.

Comment: A type implemenenting `IConvertible` or with an `operator` overload can be cast in other ways.

Comment: @newStack: Correct... But I was not trying to explain the difference betwee a cast, `is` and `as`. I was trying to explain, in short, what the difference is between cast operators and conversion.

Comment: To be fair I was being pedantic there!

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance You're right, but only if you're extremely pedantic: `o as int` is not valid, the error is: "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type" So `as` can't return `default(int)`, but it can return `default(int?)`, which technically isn't `null`, but is treated almost exactly like `null`.

Comment: In fact, the two cast operators (c-style `()` and `as`) are different as well. `as` will never perform a conversion.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - `as` does not catch cast exceptions - it uses the isinst IL instruction which returns null if the argument is not an instance of the specified type.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: `as` doesn't catch any exceptions. It's basically shorthand for `x is SomeType ? (SomeType)x : null`.

Comment: Saying that cast can only be done from base type to inheriting type is generally a bad idea (although I understand your intentions), since if this was the case, `(double)5` would be invalid instruction... We must remember that cast operators can also be overloaded.

Comment: But you must admit that `(double)5` is not a cast, it is a conversion. C# does not call it "overriding the cast operator", but it called a "conversion operator" (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473(v=vs.80).aspx). So `is` and `as` are always about casting. `(T)value` is about casting OR converting.

Answer (score 2):

[`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx) calls the [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface on the object you pass in. For types like `double` and `BigInteger`, this is implemented and converts the object to an `int` as you'd expect.

The `as` keyword does a cast; if the cast fails, it returns null. This will only work if the object is already an `int`, not just if it's a type that can be converted to `int`. E.g.

```
double d = 1.0;
object o = d;
int? i1 = o as int?; // results in null
int i2 = (int)d; // works
int i3 = Convert.ToInt32(o); //works
int i4 = Convert.ToInt32(d); //works
int i5 = (int)o; // throws an exception at run time
```